# what is runtime error in polymorphism please explain run time error in polymorphism?

Tags: hacker-news-api

what is runtime error in polymorphism please explain run time error in polymorphism?

I am expecting it resolves a call to an overridden method at runtime.IT involves the use of the reference variable of a superclass to call for an overridden method.